# Troubleshooting 404 errors form a specific IP only on Websphere

Tags: websphere, magnolia, http-trace

I have an application deployed on two Websphere instances. I can access both instances without any problems from any browser or curl/wget.
However, when requests come through the load balancer a very strange behavior takes place.

Log file:

```
10.248.11.2 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:07 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.3 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:09 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.2 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:12 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.3 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:14 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.2 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:17 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.4 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:18 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
10.248.11.4 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:18 +0200] "GET /website/home.html HTTP/1.1" 404 3093
10.248.11.3 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:19 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.2 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:22 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.3 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:24 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
10.248.11.2 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:27 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 505 -
172.17.22.162 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:14:11 +0200] "GET /website/home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 5751
10.248.11.4 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:10:15 +0200] "GET /.resources/mod/webresources/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3397
10.248.11.4 - - [03/Nov/2020:14:53:29 +0200] "GET /website/personal/loans/mortgage-loans.html HTTP/1.1" 200 4132
```

1. I receive many 505 errors on both instances from two source ip's.
2. I receive a 404 for the home page on one of the instances from a specific source ip. The same page is accessible normally from browsers. The same server serves other urls normally to the same source ip. Only that specific url causes the 404.

Unfortunately I do not have access to the load balancer. I tried to increase the log level of websphere to the maximum by choosing combined for log format and debug for trace level but still did not get more details about the error. I tried adding  com.ibm.ws.http.HttpRequest = finest and still could not find any request headers in the log file.

How can I see the request headers on Websphere and the maximum amount of details to know the source of the error?

Comment: you can dump headers through Magnolia. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Debugging+package#Debuggingpackage-Dumpheaders however, I suspect issue is in the loadbalancer itself having configured either too many or wrong insances to balance.

Comment: I suspect so too but I have no access to the load balancer so i have to troubleshoot on my side before escalating

Comment: @Jan but I also tried putting mitmproxy as a reverse proxy and magically the error disappears. I can reproduce the error. It only happens when the connection comes from the load balancer IP to a specific url (the home of the site). Also the other magnolia instance is not affected. It is very weird.